# Select rows where a column string cotains one of any values in another column

Tags: r

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL3Uo.png)
I have created a new example to make it more clear what I mean. So, there is a file with tweets that Obama posted recently. First column "number" is a number of a tweet, the second column "tweet" contains an actual tweet, the fourth one "used" contains words, three words and hashtag that were used in tweets, but somewhy we choose them. So, I wanted to select just rows which would contain any of the information in column "nottouse" and create a new dataframe with just those rows.

I have tried this:

> `used<- as.character(used[1])`
>
> > `newdata<-subset(tweets, grepl(used,tweet))`

But i guess it is not right.`

Thank you

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output for others to understand your problem better and do some coding

Comment: Sorry I did not find any way to insert an actual table

Answer (score 1):

guessing based on the structure that you have:

```
badwords <- # assign the vector of badwords
df <- # assign your dataframe of tweets

# this converts the badwords into a pattern that grepl would understand
badwords.pattern <- paste(badwords, collapse = "|")

# do subsetting by grepl
df.onlybad <- df[grepl(badwords, df$tweet),]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems to be working, but do you know how I can collapse only values in the column, because I usually get something like:  
`word|word|word|word|NA|NA\NA\NA|NA` or just `word|word|word||||||`. So I was just wondering if there is a way just to collapse the values in the column even though it has much less rows.

Comment: How about removing NA and empty words in `badwords` by doing `badwords <- na.omit(badwords); badwords <- badwords[!grepl("", badwords)]` ?